# Excel Count not blanks cells of different format

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have some excel columns with different format.

Some are blanks and returns me "1" has a result. How possible?

I have been trying to have a standardize formula. Which dint work out.

```
=COUNTIF(BG:BG,"<>")
=COUNT(BF2:BF)
=COUNT(BF:BF)
=COUNTA(BF:BF)
```

Whats the proper formula to count all NOT BLANKS cells in a column?

Comment: Hard to tell you without looking at the data, but not all cells that appear empty are necessarily empty. Have a look with `=SUMPRODUCT(--NOT(ISBLANK(BF:BF)))` to see how many cells are actually holding values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using the `IsBlank()` function? Something like (not tested):

```
=SUM(If(IsBlank(BF:BF);0;1))
```

Comment: It return a 1... I don't get it

Comment: Maybe first make a helper column, let's say "BG", and in there put the formula `=If(IsBlank(BF1);0;1)` and do this for the whole column. This should show a zero for a blank cell and a 1 for a non-blank one. Once you get this working, try to calculate the sum of that BG column.

Answer (score 0):

What is the data? I would assume you have some cells with spaces in them. If you are counting cells with numbers you could try;

=Countif(BF:BF,">"&1)

If they have words in them, try doing a trim function making a new reference column? =trim(BF2) and drop the formula down. Sorry its the best I can think of.

Comment: Hi thanks sometimes its numbers, sometimes its text